# More than one 'polyline' in SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to generate an SVG, but having multiple "Polyline" tags seems to be frustrating.
Here's my SVG code:

Image 1:

```html
<svg height="100" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<polyline id="7d47e98a-ce34-4962-a484-8953dd085399" points="0,0 1,0 1,5 3,5 3,10 6,10 6,15 10,15 10,20 15,20 15,25 " style="fill:white;stroke:red;stroke-width:1" />
</svg>
```

Image 2:

```html
<svg height="100" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<polyline id="4a2ef237-fbbf-41dd-bac5-8586f06990a4" points="0,0 1,0 1,4 3,4 3,9 6,9 6,14 10,14 10,19 15,19 15,24 " style="fill:white;stroke:green;stroke-width:1" />
</svg>
```

But when both the polylines are added in the SVG(code and result below), the result is not as expected.

Resultant Image:

```html
<svg height="100" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<polyline id="4a2ef237-fbbf-41dd-bac5-8586f06990a4" points="0,0 1,0 1,4 3,4 3,9 6,9 6,14 10,14 10,19 15,19 15,24 " style="fill:white;stroke:green;stroke-width:1" />
<polyline id="7d47e98a-ce34-4962-a484-8953dd085399" points="0,0 1,0 1,5 3,5 3,10 6,10 6,15 10,15 10,20 15,20 15,25 " style="fill:white;stroke:red;stroke-width:1" />
</svg>
```

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: result]

What am I doing wrong here?
PS: I'm very new to SVG creation by code

Comment: The fill is white, you can't see that against a white background but it's somewhat more visible against a green one. Try setting the fill to another colour e.g. blue to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: If the fill is not important to you then perhaps you want fill: none; instead.

Comment: @RobertLongson setting the fill to none seems to have achieved the desired result. I still do not understand why were the edges tapered though